# How to rename csv files and change name with each loop iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, csv

How do I change name for each csv file? I am getting new data for each token. Also can I give the csv files, the real name of token?

Example:

```
Token 492033 = kotakbank.csv, 738561 = reliance.csv, 341249 = hdfcbank.csv
```

```
i = [492033, 738561, 341249]           #Token list
for _ in list(i):
    def get_data():
        """Fetch Data from Kite"""
        to_date = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Calcutta'))
        from_date = to_date - timedelta(days=5)
        interval = '5minute'
        instrument_token = _            
        data = kite.historical_data(instrument_token, from_date, to_date, interval, continuous=False, oi=False)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
        data.index = data.date
        data.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)
        df.to_csv('datafile1.csv')               #Saving into csv file
        return data
        
df = get_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the custom filenames, you could pass the token and filename to the function like this:

```
def get_data(instrument_token, filename):
    """Fetch Data from Kite"""
    to_date = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Calcutta'))
    from_date = to_date - timedelta(days=5)
    interval = '5minute'          
    data = kite.historical_data(instrument_token, from_date, to_date, interval, continuous=False, oi=False)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.index = data.date
    data.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)
    data.to_csv(filename)               #Saving into csv file
    return data
```

Call the function like this:

```
df = get_data(492033, "kotakbank.csv")
```

You could loop it like this:

```
token_list = [[492033, "kotakbank.csv"], [738561, "reliance.csv"], [341249, "hdfcbank.csv"]]
for i in token_list:
    df = get_data(i[0], i[1])
```